# Error with CouchDB + Rail

Tags: ruby-on-rails, couchdb

I got this error with CouchDB return error with Rails application :

```
Processing Admin::WorksController#create (for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-04 17:29:16) [POST]
  Parameters: {"tag_subject"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save", "relation_meta"=>{"comment"=>"", "i18n"=>{"en"=>{"comment"=>""}}}, "action"=>"create", "authenticity_token"=>"BCeQuNvUCsF3rt+idhGid/Yy6XQWotleQxUqCbTfQSA=", "add_work"=>{"i18n"=>["", {"lang"=>""}, "", {"lang"=>""}]}, "relation"=>{"name"=>"", "from"=>"", "_id"=>"", "type"=>"0"}, "remote_picture"=>"", "controller"=>"admin/works", "work"=>{"school"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "name"=>"How name", "description_title"=>"", "source_year"=>"", "location"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "dim_height"=>"", "institution"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "original_destination"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "author"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "notes"=>"", "url"=>"", "private_collection"=>"0", "scandal_art"=>"0", "mysterious_art"=>"0", "source_person"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "dim_depth"=>"", "sponsor"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "dim_width"=>"", "description"=>"", "source_type"=>"unknown", "i18n"=>{"en"=>{"name"=>"", "description_title"=>"", "url"=>"", "description"=>"", "wikipedia_url"=>"", "analyse"=>""}}, "wikipedia_url"=>"", "creation"=>{"location"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}, "location_label"=>"", "date"=>"", "date_label"=>"", "i18n"=>{"en"=>{"location_label"=>"", "date_label"=>""}}}, "rupture_art"=>"0", "major_art"=>"0", "name_original_language"=>"fr", "state"=>"draft", "analyse"=>"", "owner"=>{"name"=>"", "_id"=>""}}}
[ES] Indexing Work 5dfa421d669d553bab3ec334ce3d157d...
[ES] Exception when saving Work 5dfa421d669d553bab3ec334ce3d157d in ES : 

Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Errno::ECONNREFUSED):
  lib/artdb/search/gummi.rb:575:in `add_to_search_index'
  lib/artdb/search/gummi.rb:585:in `add_to_search_index!'
  vendor/gems/oz-couchrest-0.29/lib/couchrest/mixins/callbacks.rb:427:in `_run_save_callbacks'
  vendor/gems/oz-couchrest-0.29/lib/couchrest/more/extended_document.rb:191:in `save'
  vendor/gems/oz-couchrest-0.29/lib/couchrest/more/extended_document.rb:189:in `catch'
  vendor/gems/oz-couchrest-0.29/lib/couchrest/more/extended_document.rb:189:in `save'
  lib/artdb/stale.rb:29:in `save'
  lib/artdb/varnish_purging.rb:37:in `save'
  app/controllers/admin/works_controller.rb:28:in `create'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/request_handler.rb:96:in `process_request'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:513:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_request_handler.rb:274:in `main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:205:in `start_request_handler'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `send'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:170:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/utils.rb:479:in `safe_fork'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:165:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:180:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/application_spawner.rb:128:in `start'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:253:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:132:in `lookup_or_add'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:246:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:82:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server_collection.rb:79:in `synchronize'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:244:in `spawn_rack_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:137:in `spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/spawn_manager.rb:275:in `handle_spawn_application'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `__send__'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:357:in `server_main_loop'
  passenger (3.0.4) lib/phusion_passenger/abstract_server.rb:206:in `start_synchronously'
  passenger (3.0.4) helper-scripts/passenger-spawn-server:99
```

But after check on CouchDB, seem object really created . Any help ? Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about CouchDB but it seems that the server you are trying to connect to doesn't accept the connection. Perhaps the service ain't running or your username/password are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks, I just resolved this issues, It's just wrong config with Elasticsearch :) Thanks for help !